# Combining multiple queries of single view in one query

Tags: mysql

I am struggling with multiple queries to combine in one query, all these are retrieving from single view for a same date range for all queries i.e.

```
SELECT business_id_fk,business_name, 
                  IFNULL(count(orderid_customer),0) AS total,
                  IFNULL(sum(CASE WHEN order_status IN ('CRD') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS crude,
                  IFNULL(sum(CASE WHEN order_status IN ('UNA') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS unassigned,
                  IFNULL(sum(CASE WHEN order_status IN ('DEL' , 'MCP' , 'CMP') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS delivered,
                  IFNULL(sum(CASE WHEN order_status IN ('CNL') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS cancelled,
                  IFNULL(sum(CASE WHEN order_status IN ( 'CAP' , 'CAD' , 'RSP' , 'RSD') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS postponed
                  FROM view_orders where order_datetime between '2017-10-01 00:00:00' and '2017-10-05 23:59:59' and parent_id IS NULL
              AND business_id_fk is not null GROUP BY business_id_fk ORDER BY total DESC;
```

The above query is to get business wise count

```
SELECT business_id_fk,business_name, 
              IFNULL(count(orderid_customer),0) AS total,
              IFNULL(sum(CASE WHEN order_status IN ('CRD') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS crude,
              IFNULL(sum(CASE WHEN order_status IN ('UNA') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS unassigned,
              IFNULL(sum(CASE WHEN order_status IN ('DEL' , 'MCP' , 'CMP') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS delivered,
              IFNULL(sum(CASE WHEN order_status IN ('CNL') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS cancelled,
              IFNULL(sum(CASE WHEN order_status IN ( 'CAP' , 'CAD' , 'RSP' , 'RSD') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS postponed,
              IFNULL(SUM(total), 0) AS 'Estimated_Revenue',
              IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN order_status IN ('DEL' , 'MCP', 'CMP') THEN total ELSE 0 END), 0) AS 'Generated_Revenue'
              FROM view_orders
              WHERE order_datetime between '2017-10-01 00:00:00' and '2017-10-05 23:59:59'
              AND parent_id IS NULL
              AND business_id_fk is null
              ORDER BY total DESC;
```

This is to get the count of business_id_fk having null values

```
 select ((SELECT ifnull(count(*),0) as 'total' FROM view_orders where (sla_del_datetime > delivery_datetime) and order_datetime between '2017-10-01 00:00:00' and '2017-10-05 23:59:59' and parent_id is null group by business_id_fk) / (SELECT ifnull(count(*),0) as 'total' FROM view_orders where order_status in('DEL','MCP','CMP') order_datetime between '2017-10-01 00:00:00' and '2017-10-05 23:59:59' and and parent_id is null group by business_id_fk)*100) as 'sla_adherence';
```

This query is to get sla_adherence of each business wise and non business

```
select ((SELECT ifnull(count(*),0) as 'total' FROM view_orders where order_status in('DEL','MCP','CMP') order_datetime between '2017-10-01 00:00:00' and '2017-10-05 23:59:59' and and parent_id is null group by business_id_fk) / (SELECT ifnull(count(*),0) as 'total' FROM view_orders where order_datetime between '2017-10-01 00:00:00' and '2017-10-05 23:59:59' and parent_id is null group by business_id_fk)*100) as 'strike_rate';
```

This query is to get strike_rate of each business wise and non business

I want the result like

business_id_fk||business_name||total||crude||unassigned||delivered||cancelled||postponed||Estimated_Revenue||Generated_Revenue||sla_adherence||strike_rate

1||abc||10||1||..|..|..|..|..|..|..|..|..|x.xx|x.xx
.
.
.
null(non business)||null||..|..|. . . . . . |x.xx|x.xx
each business wise rows for all the above fields and for non business.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: lean how to format sql in a question. all that is required is a 4 character indent. There is a button {} in the toolbar that will help do this too.

Comment: Do tuo want to obtain the rows from the first sql and the rows of the second sql in the same results? Or do you want to aggregate them and sum values?

Comment: Yes, I want to get rows of first and second sql in same result @kiks73

Comment: Can anyone help me out in this issue, I am stuck in getting result.

Answer (score 0):

One first query is multi-row, the second seems to be a single value. So if those assumptions are right you could try a cross join:

```
SELECT
        business_id_fk
      , business_name
      , IFNULL(count(orderid_customer),0) AS total
      , IFNULL(sum(CASE WHEN order_status IN ('CRD') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS crude
      , IFNULL(sum(CASE WHEN order_status IN ('UNA') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS unassigned
      , IFNULL(sum(CASE WHEN order_status IN ('DEL' , 'MCP' , 'CMP') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS delivered
      , IFNULL(sum(CASE WHEN order_status IN ('CNL') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS cancelled
      , IFNULL(sum(CASE WHEN order_status IN ( 'CAP' , 'CAD' , 'RSP' , 'RSD') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS postponed
      , cj.sla_adherence
FROM view_orders
CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT (
            (SELECT ifnull(count(*),0) FROM view_orders where (sla_del_datetime > delivery_datetime) and parent_id is null ) 
             /
            (SELECT ifnull(count(*),0) FROM view_orders where order_status in('DEL','MCP','CMP') and parent_id is null )*100.0
            ) as 'sla_adherence' 
      ) cj
WHERE order_datetime between '2017-08-01 00:00:00' and '2017-10-01 23:59:59'
GROUP BY business_id_fk, business_name, cj.sla_adherence
ORDER BY total DESC
;
```

Comment: Thanks Used_By_Already for the answer, result for sla_adherence is giving same for all business names.

Comment: Yes. That is what I  mentioned. The second query returns a single value. You need to be more definitive about your requirements.  You simply asked for 2 queries to be combined.